# Is it possible to target both adjacent neighbors of a div

Tags: css, html

I want to find out if it is possible to target both neighboring elements using the middle one?

for example:

```
<div>
   <span class="icon">icon</span>
   <input id="input" class="input error" type="text" />
   <label for="input"></label>
<div>
```

When the input has the **error** class I want to target the *label* and the *span* to have the color red.

I managed to make the *label* red with the following:

```
input.error ~ label {
    color: red;
}
```

However I've had no luck with the span. Can somebody maybe tell me if this is possible? and if so please help.

Comment: Not possible but if you are adding that class to the input why not just add it to the parent div instead ?

Comment: No, you can't affect elements up the DOM in CSS, only down

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I'm still very very new to javascript. I'm using jquery validate which adds the class to the input for me. I'll check if I can add the class to the label as DaniP suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox with the `order` property to re-order the elements visually, while having the `input` as the first element in the DOM so you can use the general sibling selector.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
.icon {
  order: -1;
}
input.error ~ * {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="input" class="input error" type="text">
  <span class="icon">icon</span>
  <label for="input">label</label>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to target the span and add a class to it.

Comment: Your question was never tagged with JavaScript, let alone jQuery. If you were looking for a jQuery solution you should have tagged your question with it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find out if it is possible to target both neighboring
>   elements using the middle one?

You can use the **axe** selector `%` to target both neighbouring elements.

Since there is no shared class or element type between `.icon` and `label`, you'll need to declare:

```
input.error % .icon,
input.error % label {
color: red;
}
```

Alternatively, (in this case) you might combine the CSS immediate subsequent sibling selector `+` and the **axe** immediate previous sibling selector `?`:

```
input.error ? .icon,
input.error + label {
color: red;
}
```